# Best way for saving storage when customizing text attribute in an Android app?

Tags: android

I'm currently making this app that will storage a lot of internal data (it's like an offline catalog sort of thing).

I'm implementing the text, according to internet you can customize the text attributes of a button/spinner in any of these three ways:

1. Create a custom TextView layout.
2. Change the text size with the android:textSize attribute.
3. Change the text color with android:textColor in the new style file.

Which one uses up less storage?

Thanks.

Comment: Which one cost less space? Which space you are referring to? View properties will not affect your storage

Comment: yes, I mean storage

Comment: when you mean View properties are you referring to customizing the text size attribute for each button?

Comment: Yes your data is separate and view properties are separate